# Android UI - views slider

Tags: android, user-interface, view, custom-component

I need an android component that will hold two views (one on top, and the second one ont he bottom). There will also be a slider between views.

It will look something like this:
[image: component holding two views]

View 1 is bigger than shown and user can expand it by moving down the separator (dark grey rectangle on the picture above). While expanding, View 2 will go down and will not be covered by View 1 (not like in android's notification panel).

Is there some kind of ready to use library for this? If not - could you point me in the right direction how to achieve this?

Comment: as far i know there is no readymade api like this

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this but I think you can scale the view by draggin. see [this](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html#scale) to know about this method.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is from years ago, but I've had the same problem recently. Now that we can do nice things with the Design library with scrolling and resizing, this question has become even more important.

So I'd like to point out a library called [SubAppBarPanel](https://github.com/dadouf/SubAppBarPanel), that allows you to expand an area from below the app bar. When it's expanded, it pushes down the main content (see [GIF](https://github.com/dadouf/SubAppBarPanel#subappbarpanel)).